# tvOS - UITextField shows white on white when focused

Tags: uitextfield, interface-builder, tvos

I've created a UITextField on a screen using a custom font (Skia 100 point) and sitting on top of a UIImageView, but otherwise it is quite unremarkable. When it's not focused, the text shows normally, if a bit faint:

[image]

When it is focused, however, the entire area renders as a solid white rectangle:

[image]

I'd be willing to compromise on the look and feel of this screen if I could get it to render normally when focused, but nothing I've tried has changed it--I always get white-on-white. I read about a similar issue where they said this was due to custom background colors but I have not set a background color. In fact, even if I set a custom text color, it does not seem to take effect--it looks the same.

Comment: Did you try changing Appearance attribute in storyboard for text field, try light or dark...

Comment: Good thought. I switched it from Dark to Default and now the letters show up as medium gray instead of white. It seems like a bug in tvOS but for now it's better than nothing!

Comment: Yup I think there is a bug open, as if we try to change color on updateFocus method its not taking effect

Comment: Filed as rdar://24314619 - UITextField in "Appearance: Dark" mode appears solid white when selected